# Parameter passed to ASP.NET Core Controller using ajax is always null

Tags: c#, ajax, string, asp.net-core, null

I am upgrading mvc application to .Net Core and am having difficulty passing a string value via ajax to the controller.  I have tried various solutions I found on the web (`[FormBody]`, prefixing with `=`, and some others), but no luck.  The value is always null.  What has changed in Core that I need to fix?

```
      var result = "";

  $.ajax({
      url: "https://......./api/lookups/Search",
      type: "POST",
      data: JSON.stringify(g),
      async: false,
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      success: function (data) {
       result = data;
    },
    done: function (data) {
       result = data;
    },
       fail: function (data) {
       result = data;
    },
       error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       alert('request failed :' + errorThrown);
    }
});


using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace zpmAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class LookupsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private zBestContext db = new zBestContext();

        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public string sayHello()
        {
            return "hello";
        }

        [HttpPost]
        //[Route("api/Lookups/LocationSearch")]
        public JsonResult LocationSearch(GeneralSearch g)
        {
            return new JsonResult( "hello from LocationSearch");
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried `data: { g: JSON.stringify(g)}`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It appears I have been dealing with a Cors issue now have it working using the modified coded below in the Startup.cs and Controller.

The drawback to this is that "Content-Type: 'application/json'" must be added to the header on the client side in order it to work.  I would prefer not to do this because it would require the customers to make the update to their code.  Everything I have read says the shown modifications to the Startup.cs file should allow me to process with out modifying the post header, but the Application seams to be ignoring it.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using dbzBest.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace zpmAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    [ApiController]
    [Consumes("application/json")]
    public class PropertyController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public List<PropertyTile> Search(PropertySearch s)
        {
            try
            {
                List<PropertyTile> tiles = new List<PropertyTile>();
                dbzBest.Data.Properties db = new dbzBest.Data.Properties();
                tiles = db.Search(s);
                return tiles;
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                PropertyTile e = new PropertyTile();
                e.Description = ex.Message;
                List<PropertyTile> error = new List<PropertyTile>();
                error.Add(e);
                return error;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the Startup.cs file

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {

                app.UseHsts();
            }

            /*add this line for CORS*/
            app.UseCors(opt => opt.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your controller action (that I am assuming is configured to accept POST requests)

`public string LoadChildrenAccounts(string parentID)`

accepts a bare string as parameter but you are POSTing an object with a property of type string (`{ "parentID": "12345" }`).

Try changing `data: stringify({ "parentID": "12345" })` to `data: JSON.stringify("12345")`

Comment: Yes,  there is a [HttpPost] attribute on the controller action.

Tried your suggestion, but no luck :(

I did however change the procedure to httpGet and it worked:

        [HttpGet]
        public string LoadChildrenAccounts(string id)
        {
***Code Stuff Here ***

}

Comment: This has helped, thanks.  Still working thought it and expect to provide a more detailed update by this weekend.